# If electron carries negative charge, why bother looking for it's electric dipole moment?

Tags: electrons, dipole-moment

I got confused after reading about spherical electron, would there really be some type of unknown particles popping in and out of existence within the virtual particle cloud around the electron that give electron it's property? Why is it important for the electron to have electric dipole moment?

Comment: See the question I have linked. If the electron has a dipole moment that would be evidence for physics beyond the Standard Model.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I only know they're measuring the tiny difference between the center of mass and center of charge of the electron inside electric field using laser, I like to know why are they doing this and if there is how does it help explain there are more matter than antimatter?

Comment: That is exactly what the question I've linked discusses.

Comment: If the electron had a dipole moment it would indicate that the charge distribution isn't spherical, which is of interest.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two classical static electric charges and wish to compute potentials and electric field, you can approximate with multipole expansion.

Because, you can have separately charged particles. Contrast to magnetism, there is no such thing as magnetic monopole.